# Complex Nested JSON Conversion to Data Table without creating class in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Title",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "location": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "dagno": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "pattano": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "pattatype": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "landclass": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "bigha": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "katha": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "lessa": {
        "type": "string"
        },
        "pid": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": [
            {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "pdarid": {
                "type": "string"
                },
                "pdarname": {
                "type": "string"
                },
                "pdarfather": {
                "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "pdarid",
                "pdarname",
                "pdarfather"
            ]
            }
        ]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "location",
        "dagno",
        "pattano",
        "pattatype",
        "landclass",
        "bigha",
        "katha",
        "lessa",
        "pid"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why would you **not** create a class? When you have a class you could easily desirialze your JSON object?

Comment: Actually, I want to show the elements to the user based on  JSON that they upload, There may multiple users with different JSON so  I not fixing the elements by creating a class.